# losing quality and size , after adding watermark to image

Tags: php, image

I'm working on a website which I didn't originally create/develop.

Users can upload an image and when they do that, there's a function that creates a duplicate of that image with a watermark.

But the copy with the watermark is of low quality and also its size is much smaller than the original image

[Without watermark](http://img.akstube.ir/images/2013/05/DSC_0168_69_70_tonemapped.jpg)

[With watermark](http://img.akstube.ir/images/2013/05/irwm_DSC_0168_69_70_tonemapped.jpg)

```
function watermark( $path ){
    $watermark = imagecreatefrompng('files/watermark.png');
    $wmsize = getimagesize('files/watermark.png');
    $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($path);
    $size  = getimagesize($path);

    $dest_x = (8);
    $dest_y =  ($size[1] - 35  );

    imagecopy($image, $watermark, $dest_x, $dest_y, 0, 0, $wmsize[0], $wmsize[1]);

    ob_start(); 
    imagejpeg($image); 
    $img2 = ob_get_contents(); 
    ob_end_clean(); 
    imagedestroy($image);
    return $img2 ;
}
```

Comment: Why are you adding a watermark to an image that already has a watermark? Are you one of those websites that aggregates content that isn't yours?

Comment: @remyabel no it's a image sharing website , the original uploader added his own watermark before uploading it , you can see his name in the right side of watermarked image is the same as the first image  , and thanx for the down vote

Answer (score 1):

The image quality is decreased because of JPEG compression.

Every time you save image as JPEG you decrease its quality because JPEG uses lossy compression. You can minimize the loss by setting the compress quality to 100%, but if you would like to perform lossless compression it is not possible for JPEG and you must look for another image format, e.g. TIFF.

Comment: but the original image itself is a jpeg , are you saying each jpeg copy is going to have a lower quality than older one ? is it even possible to create a tiff from jepeg with php ? thanx

Comment: @max I believe it is possible to save image file as TIFF image, by using GD library. For more info see [PHP Image Processing Manual](http://cz1.php.net/manual/en/book.image.php). But since the purpose of your website is to share images it wouldn't be wise to change format of the image that user uploads. I recommend to stick with setting the compress quality to 100%, it should resolve your problem.